# What is happening when I increase the border-right in this case?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to pull this off:

[image]

This is the code:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  backgroundColor: #F7524C;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#cutShape {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 416px solid blue;
    border-top: 300px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="cutShape" />
</div>
```

When I increase the border-right any more than 416px to match the wrapper width which is 426 to get rid of the that little piece of red on the left side, the whole div becomes blue. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this and use a simple gradient coloration:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background: 
    /*                                                  position/width height */
    linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,#F7524C 50%) top/100% 50% no-repeat,
    blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

With two elements:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:10px;
  background: #F7524C;
}
.box > div {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:inherit;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,blue 50%) top/100% 50%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom/100% 50.5%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot do that. Because I need to separate the content of both the wrapper and inner div

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.